# Google+ Style "Send Feedback"

Tags: ajax

Does anyone know a service that offers a google+ style feedback system? It seems that it would be a great way to get feedback from users. If you have not seen it before. I've attached a screen shot.

It allows users highlight the problem and also blank out parts thy don't want to show. [image]

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: Jonathan you are correct. I don't believe this is a duplicate question either. Is there a way to move it over there or do I need to do a new post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Saber Feedback (was BugMuncher)](https://saberfeedback.com/).

It seems like Google's Feedback system might at some point be made a service of its own, and they have a page where you can [register interest](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlefeedbackregisterinterest/).

If your needs are more for things like sharing annotations rather than specifically bugs that'll require screenshots, you might have a look at [CoViews](http://www.covie.ws/).

Comment: I took a look at BugMuncher. It looks like it launched a few days ago. I'll have to keep an eye on it. I hope that google's comes out.

Comment: Usersnap is also worth a try. It integrates with existing bug tracking tools, so you don't need to change your workflow. http://www.usersnap.com

Comment: For anyone coming to this very old answer, BugMuncher was renamed as Saber Feedback in 2018. Same product, different name.