# Let tester directly click on web site to report bugs, similar to bugherd?

Tags: web-development, website-design, users, testing

I'm doing website User Testing and want them to report issues by clicking on web site and type text into a comment box. Similar to [diigo.com](http://www.diigo.com/) or [bugherd.com](http://www.bugherd.com/)

Bugherd is designed for this but it is still at an early stage -- too unstable for our production use as of Aug 2011. (Very impressive, though.)

Diigo is not designed for bug tracking. It kind of works but I can't really integrate with our bug-fixing workflow.

Apart from the obvious screenshot->save image->upload image to a bug tracker, are there ways to allow our users to easily point-and-click and input bugs?

Comment: See my answer on [this previous question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/google-style-send-feedback/17188#17188). (I'll leave it to you to decide whether this is quite a duplicate and flag for closing if so.)

Comment: [Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) allows you to get accurate screenshots from your visitors - it even integrates with existing bug trackers.

Answer (score 2):

[SnapEngage](http://www.snapengage.com/) lets visitors report bugs directly from the page they're viewing. It's aimed at site owners who want to offer live support, but they have an 'offline' mode which lets users report issues when you're not around. It includes client-side screenshot functionality (requires Java on the client).

You might also consider rolling your own solution by [creating screenshots on the client-side using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots), then uploading them to your server when the user posts the report.